# Why is this parenthesis of a difference size?

Tags: macros

I have the following LaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\lit}[1]{{\texttt #1}}
 \lit{()} \lit{(hello)} \lit{(}\lit{)} 
\lit{hello}
\end{document}
```

which produces the following output:

[image]

I'm curious to know why the first two closing parenthesis are of a different style to their opening ones.  Any ideas?

Comment: `\texttt` just acts only on the first `(` since you forgot `\texttt{#1}` ;-) This implies a font switch back to font before `\texttt` was specified, which means that the closing `)` is of different size

Comment: In your example with `()` you used explicitly two calls to `\lit` and therefore the parentheses are accidently correct

Comment: Not only the () are wrong but the `h` of the second hello is in a different  font to `ello` (for the same reason)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: True, I missed that, it is hard to see.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer it's only hard to see after the shock of theinitial glance acts like a poke in the eye and it takes you a while to recover:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: When I wrote my comments, it was on a small smartphone display, so the different characters `h` did not really differ ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
\newcommand{\lit}[1]{{\texttt #1}}
\lit{()}
```

After one expansion step `\lit{()}` becomes:

```
\texttt ()
```

`\texttt` takes *one* argument, written with braces:

```
\texttt{(})
```

Thus the first open parentheses is written in the typewriter font, the second isn't.

Therefore you need curly braces around `#1`:

```
\newcommand{\lit}[1]{\texttt{#1}}
```

Answer (score 6):

heiko's answer is good, but there's another way:

```
\newcommand{\lit}[1]{{\ttfamily #1}}
```

`\ttfamily` is "persistent"; it affects everything in the following text until the
end of the group.  it's parallel to `\bfseries` or `\itshape`.